# Geting the first image url from a post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a dynamic website, I have a database with some news, and I wanted to get the first image from the post content
The news are added to this database with wordpress, as you know wordpress images are inside the `post_content`.

Please can you help me to get the first image of the post and dispay the link.

Thank you

Comment: Seems like this should be moved to the WordPress Development Stack Exchange. Also I'm wondering if there's a core WordPress function to do this. Maybe WP's "featured" image function had could have an extra parameter to auto discover/generate an image based on the content--that would be awesome.

Answer (score 6):

Put this in your functions.php file:

```
function get_first_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

    if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
        $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
    }
    return $first_img;
}
```

and then simply call the function on the page you need to get the first image of the post like this:

```
<?php echo get_first_image() ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I am trying to create a php dynamic website, i dont want anymore to use wordpress, i just need that database, not the system. i have looked around but havent found smth how to get the first image url from a row,and display it.

Thank you

Comment: No problem!  If the answer worked for you I would appreciate if you accepted the answer under the +1 button.

Comment: please read what i have writed, i it is not what i am looking for.

Comment: So everything is still in the same wordpress database but you need to use custom SQL calls and php rather than using Wordpress built-in methods?

Comment: So the only thing that i will have from wordpress, will be only the database, nothing else. The php calls are totally custom. is why i am asking to get a script that do the things i  have said. Thanks

Comment: just include `wp-load.php` from the wordpress source (download it if you don't have it), and then you can use wordpress functions.

Comment: i am trying to create the new php , cus wordpress is getin many resourses from my server, the there are too many connections with database, some from them are not needed, what will i import with this wp-load.php ? is any other way to get the first img url ? thnx

Comment: also wanted to ask, if any thing wrong if i will create only an index.php  and not , header.php, index.php, sidebar.php footer php etc. so only 1 file will have all this, smth wrong here ? thnx

Comment: I think this secondary question is becoming complicated enough it might qualify for a second post with the full question worded again.  Just make sure to give us a link to it

Comment: please can you help with the first question, thnx

Comment: sorry for spamm, but i need some  help about my problem, any one can help please ?

Comment: I suggested reposting another question.  Your initial question asked for the wordpress implementation.  If you post another with your updated description of the question, I'm sure people would be happy to respond, as of now - what you want is a bit unclear with this lengthy comment section.